# Where to find SSDT in Visual studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, package, sql-server-2014

I need to create a new SSIS project for my SQLserver project to fill the database.
Where can I find the SSDT to get to the integration services.
And what are the steps to follow in order to prepare the Package fully for use.

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Open visual studio..

Go to create new project, it will open a new window, click on business intelligence option, it will show integration services project

[image]

Comment: Thank you . I've figured it out !

Comment: Do you know how to continue from there ?

Comment: you have to search for integration services tutorials, just google it. if this answer is what you are looking for you have to [accept it](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: this is a good place to start https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-how-to-create-an-etl-package

Comment: @SonaLegends still waiting for a reply!!